# what's the difference between Element and Element ID?

Tags: css

what's the difference between Element and Element ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div id="element-id"></div>
```

The element is `div`, the element's ID is `element-id`.

Note that every ID should be unique in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

In the DOM, an Element is what you would call a "tag" in HTML-speak, for example `<a id="myanchor">Hello world!</a>`. That Element's ID is `myanchor`.

This answers the question, but I'm not sure if it's what you wanted to know... and it has nothing to do with `css-layout`.

Comment: A tag is the structure of the element, and is not synonymous with the element itself. They include start and end tags.

Answer (score 0):

CSS has many selectors:

```
a           { color: red; }    - all hyperlinks
#firstname  { color: red; }    - any html object with id: firstname
.firstname  { color: red; }    - any html object with class: firstname
```

For more info: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

The element is the actual HTML element (tag).
The element's ID is the HTML element's id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Element {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
This will affect all elements form this type

Element#ID{
 border: 1px solid red;
} Will affect the element with this ID only if it is form the spcified type (Element)

Examples:

div{
  color: red;
} All inputs will have red text

div#my_input{
  color: red;
} my_input will have red text only if it is a DIV